# omission "get" in parallel structure

Tags: parallelism

> 1.The higher the sun gets, the hotter the day gets.
>
> 2.The higher the sun, the hotter the day.

Which is more natural? We need to omit "get" in both clause to be natural?

Comment: This is just a matter of taste, not of English grammar or idiom - although No 2 is crisper and sweeter.

Comment: The second is not a sentence, as it has no verbs. It is a construction common in proverbs, but otherwise is rather literary.

Answer (score 1):

I think your sentences have two slightly different meanings

> The higher the sun gets, the hotter the day gets.

describes the relationship of the sun and temperature on a given day.

> The higher the sun, the hotter the day.

more describes the habitual relationship of the sun and temperature in general.